# decipher RGXWSTLSQLITL where (ABCDEF=QWERTY)

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

> decipher RGXWSTLSQLITL  where (ABCDEF=QWERTY)

How do you solve this?

Answer (score 28):

If ABCDEF = QWERTY, then:

`1    Q W E R T Y U I O P    =    A B C D E F G H I J`
`2     A S D F G H J K L     =     K L M N O P Q R S`
`3      Z X C V B N M        =      T U V W X Y Z`

So RGXWSTLSQLITL becomes

> DOUBLESLASHES.

Comment: Beaten by SECONDSSSS

Comment: I have a question. If I am beaten to an answer, would it be proper Puzzling SE etiquette to delete my answer?

Comment: @NL628 You *can*, but you certainly aren't *expected* to. I've already upvoted your answer. In fact, having multiple good answers makes us more likely to hit the HNQ and make more rep out of this ;-) (not that *I* need it, but ...)

Comment: Wow I am talking to the legendary Randal'Thor. #1 Most Reputation wanting MOARRRR. Lol okay then. :)) Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @NL628 Hey, I'm trying to get *you* more rep here! :-P I've already got two PSE answers on HNQs right now, so this one is probably just going to mean wasted upvotes anyway.

Comment: FWIW, I don't view an identical answers created within seconds of another as a duplicate that need deletion, and generally make it a point to upvote both of them. It's different when the answers are separated by hours or even days, though (often by someone new).

Answer (score 21):

The answer is:

> DOUBLESLASHES

Because

> Counting from the top of the keyboard, replace each letter with the correspondingly positioned letter in the alphabet.